# JS: Is it possible "something(arg)" and "something.my_method(arg)" at same time

Tags: javascript, function, oop, methods

I know how create just a function `something(arg)`

```
something = function(arg) {
 console.log('Function result', arg);
}
```

I know how create an object with function `something.my_method(arg)`

```
something = {
  my_method: function(arg) {
    console.log('Method result', arg);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to write code, wher both `something(arg)` and `something.my_method(arg)` are exists?

**Like this**
In file:

```
// Needed code

something(123)
something.my_method(234)
```

Output in console:

```
Function result 123
Function result 234
```

Comment: Sure, just add a property to the first one. Functions are objects and all objects can have properties and methods. Don't override it though, assign it like `something.my_method = function() {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Well, this is javacript, and there are many ways to do it.*

edit: I actually thought about this, and tried to imagine other way to do the same thing, and actually I cannot find any. There's @elcodedocle which I thought about but is close but not what you ask, or otherwise any other solution is a rewrite like his or like the one I suggest below.

The quick and dirty way is to create your function:

```
something = function(arg) {
    console.log('Function result', arg);
}
```

and then create a property that holds the other function:

```
something.my_method = function(arg) {
    console.log('Method result', arg);
}
```

Though I'd have to warn you that if you *need* to do such a thing for anything else than pure intellectual and academical curiosity, you might want to rethink the design of your code. That kind of "trick" is never elegant and usually misleading your future code readers (which can be *you* in six months).

Answer (score 0):

short in one function:

```
function something(arg) {
    something.my_method = function (arg) {
        console.log('Method result', arg);
    }
    console.log('Function result', arg);
}
```

Comment: indeed, but if you call `something.my_method()` before `something()` you'll get a `TypeError: something.my_method is not a function` error. So this is basically just a rewrite of the other QND solution.

Comment: @zmo, that's right. but according to the specs, it works.

Answer (score 0):

To define a method on an object, you can extend its `prototype`. Since `something` is a function, you want to overwrite the `Function` prototype:

```
Function.prototype.my_method = function(arg) {
    console.log("My method result", arg);
}
function something(arg) {
    console.log("My function result", arg);
}
something(123);
something.my_method(345)
```

which outputs:

```
My function result 123
My method result 345
```

A more interesting question however is why on earth you would want to do this :-)

Comment: I write jQuery plugins like [this](https://github.com/iserdmi/scrollport-js). And I have jQuery method `$.fn.scrollport()`, for initiate scroll, and `$.fn.scrollport_link()` for create scroll links. I thin it is better to create `$.fn.scrollport.link()` instead `$.fn.scrollport_link`